# Deploying MVC 3 with Code First EF , also using Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to deploy my first MVC website (using arvixe as my host) and I'm having problems with the database. When I develop on my local and I change anything on my Models (mapped on my DbContext) it wipes out my database and creates a new one (if it exists) or just completely create a database for my entities.

With that said, my problem is when I deploy it, my project that has all the controllers gets deployed and I can access my landing page but once I try to login (which triggers the creating of a database on my local) it will just give me an error and wouldn't try to create the database.

Not really sure what I'm missing on the steps, should I be creating the database at least without the records first?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions problem.  The account you are running on your server most likely does not have permissions to DROP/CREATE tables.

When deploying to production / hosted server I generally do not rely on EF to create my schema. I copy my CREATE tabel scripts from my DEV enviorment to PRODUCTION and make sure my DBCONTEXT intialisation code is set NOT TO make any changes.

Comment: this seems like the way to go, i was just reading this > http://stackoverflow.com/a/10760985/639713 and apparently i have to generate scripts to run? is that right? i tried doing that and it has been 15 min and no table was created..not sure what's wrong.. also, what do u mean by "make sure my DBCONTEXT intialisation code is set NOT TO make any changes." ?

Comment: if you have `DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>());
` you may need to change DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges to some other setting

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
public class YourDbContext: DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext()
        : base("name = YourConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourDbContext, YourMigrationsConfiguration>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Your Building Rules
    }

    #region DbSets
    public DbSet<YourTable> YourTables { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class YourMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourDbContext>
{
    public YourMigrationsConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(YourDbContext context)
    {
        /*sql script*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the only way I can do the same thing that my App does in my local to my host is to have sysadmin permissions/account to drop the dbase. which is not happening...ever.. So I decided to just generate a script and run it remotely. I'm not sure how it will affect my database once i start doing alterations on tables and maintenance on the data. wish me luck.

oh btw, here's my source for the script

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760985/639713